# Detecting Whole Words for JAVA

Tags: java

Currently with my program, if the user inputs "cat" then the chatbot would spit back out "Tell me more about your pets." as expected. However this is also true if the letters cat are part of another word. So a word like catch  would be picked up as catch and the chatbot would return "Tell me more about your pets." How else would I go about to polish up the keyword detection?

if (statement.indexOf("cat") >=0) {
     response = "Tell me more about your pets.";

Comment: `if (statement.equals("cat"))` ?

Comment: caterina -> tell me more about your pets

Comment: Can't the statement be longer than a single word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of ways to improve keyword detection:

- Create a list/set of the keywords to compare to
- Use the split(" ") function on your string to only get words (it returns a String[] that you can loop through)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bcat\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Hello the cat is cool");
boolean cat;
if(matcher.find()) {
  cat = true;
} else {
  cat = false;
}
```

Using `\\b` in the pattern, ensures that only full words are matched.